# Why setTimeout() function runs only once?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am making a javascript bookmarklet that resizes all images, periodically.

```
javascript: function x(){
    for(i=0;i<=document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;i++)
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].width+=1;
};
t = window.setTimeout("x()",100);
void(0);
```

But it runs only once. What is the problem here??

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Also your for loop at the end probably meant to be `i++`.

Comment: You shouldn't do `i<=document.getElementsByTagName('img').length`. You're reselecting all the images in the document as many times as there are images. You should cache the selection. `var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); for( var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++ )` Notice also that I did `<` instead of `<=` as well.

Comment: seems kind of useless because if you don't stop the timer images will grow forever.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you looking for `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` by any chance?

```
t = window.setInterval("x()",100);
```

Comment: But still can this task be achieved by setTimeout()? I tried place statement in x() function and it didnt worked.

Comment: @Shubham: I believe so but I'm not sure how. I do know you're one step there.

Comment: @Shubham yes you can do it with setTimeout(), I added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same code properly indented for clarity

```
function x() {
    for(i=0;i<=document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;++)
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].width+=1;
};
t = window.setTimeout("x()",100);
void(0);
```

window.setTimout() executes the passed code only once because it is meant to. If you want to execute code more often, use window.setInterval().

Comment: I think it is just the `i++`.

Comment: @Thilo True. Though this is something that the error console should have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `i++` at the end of your for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a syntax error.

for(i=0;i<=document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;**i++**)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the...

```
t = window.setTimeout("x()",100);
```

inside the function x() brackets {  } and it works with SetTimeout()

```
function x() {
    for(i=0;i<=document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;i++)
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].width+=1;

t = window.setTimeout("x()",100);
};

    x();

void(0);
```

You can only call x() after all the images have been loaded on the page or there is an error.

Answer (score -2):

<s>It might be `window.setTimeOut("x",100)`</s>

Edit : correct the answer to this `window.setTimeout(x,100)`.

PS: thats what happens if you simply work with a IDEs.

Comment: Your capitalization of `setTimeout` isn't right, and `"x"` won't do anything.

Comment: @patrick, you are right about both. It should have been this window.setTimeout(x,100) .

Comment: it has to be    x() so it refers to a function